# blender headless video editing renders black video

Tags: python, blender

When I use the script in debug mode with blender UI opened - it renders fine. As soon as I run headless mode it renders the video as a black screen with no sound.

I am rendering 4k images sequence as a video with sound.

Here is a setup I use:

```
####Headless run command:  'blender.exe' -b -P blender_editor.py -- -someargs

scene = bpy.context.scene

last_strip = scene.sequence_editor.sequences[-1]
scene.frame_end = last_strip.frame_final_end


# scene.sequence_editor.use_preview_range = True
scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
scene.render.resolution_y = 1080
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = "FFMPEG"
scene.render.ffmpeg.format = "MPEG4"
scene.render.ffmpeg.codec = 'H264'
scene.render.ffmpeg.constant_rate_factor = "PERC_LOSSLESS"



scene.render.filepath = "path/to/output"
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The interesing thing is that, after spending a whole day on this issue, I noticed that seems like the strips that are created on the graphical interface is not visible when you use it in headless mode.

Only the strips I insert while in headless mode are the ones that are rendered.
Still couldnt find how to solve this.